# Does wordpress site need optimization

Tags: wordpress, web-services, optimization, cdn, pagespeed

I was told that since wordpress websites are already on the cloud they don't need optimization such as that of CDN, Gzip compression etc. Is it true?

Comment: do you mean Wordpress.com hosted sites? they lack in functionality and much harder to customize.

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird assumption but let's check that. WordPress optimization tutorials usually recommend having one or more of the following:

1. Caching Plugins - such as W3 Total Cache, WP-Rocket - to control your files' caching properties more easily.
2. CDN for worldwide fast content(files, images etc...) delivery - good mostly for content heavy global sites.
3. Good server settings - which will include GZIP compression settings, compatible PHP version installed and other settings set by your hosting company.

regarding 1-2 - that's up to you. 3 depends ofcourse on your hosting company. you should check it with them.

hope it helped,
enjoy

Answer (score 0):

It actually need a few optimizations just depends in what content you serve etc.

For example we at College UBT - www.ubt-uni.net use wordpress with optimizations such as Nginx webserver with google pagespeed module + PHP Cache and site opens very fast.

Recently I am seeing very good reviews about WP Rocket so have a look into it they seem to be very serious but you have to pay the plugin Annually.